# MediaWiki distributed wiki plugin

Tags: administration, mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

I was wondering if something like this already exists or not — I would like to have a distributed wiki that is hosted on various servers using MediaWiki. Basically, this would affect searches and "internal" links.

- When I search, it would check its local repository/db for content first, then append results from other distributed MediaWiki servers.
- When I click an internal `[[Link]]`, it would try to route me to a page within the wiki entitled "Link", and if that page didn't exist locally, it would try to route me to the "first" occurrence of "Link" on another Wiki server. ("First" is subjective because I don't know what logic determines where to route if two other servers have a page by that name.)

The purpose of this request is because of

1. Capacity - I only want to be responsible for maintaining my wiki's capacity (such as space and backup).
2. Administration - I only want to administer/organize my wiki, and let other people have stewardship over their wikis.
3. Scope of content contribution - The content in my wiki will be built by those who are in my organization, and I do not want nor expect people in my organization to have to contribute information about topics outside of their organization.

The use case is I am within a company, and I want my department to have a wiki where we start contributing, and another organization can independently maintain (and format and administer, etc.) their own wiki. The scope of content contributed will be per organization — as in, it is unlikely I'd ever contribute information to another org's wiki. All orgs already use a common LDAP for authentication. Persisting sessions is a different story, not necessarily required, because again, I am likely not going to edit the page of another org.

Does something like this concept exist? If so, what is it called, because I am not getting anything that matches when I search for distributed wiki.

Or is there a better way to solve what I am after?

Comment: this is off-topic here, I'd check over at softwarerecs.se

Comment: I am specifically asking about a plugin for MediaWiki, not an alternative to it. MediaWiki is my base, so I do not need any recommendations about that. If not a plugin then perhaps a better way to accomplish what I am after (from an administration stand point). I already see a ton of similar questions on here regarding MediaWiki administration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [list of distributed MediaWiki proposals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:HaeB/Timeline_of_distributed_Wikipedia_proposals), but I don't think anyone ever implemented something like that - it's a lot harder than it might sound at first. There were definitely wikis using a frontend/backend setup (ie. if the page does not exist, pull it from Wikipedia), not sure how they were implemented. [RPED](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RPED) is the closest extension I could find right now.